# Finding the points P and Q

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, coordinate-systems

**Find points P,Q which are closest possible with P lying on the line**

**x = 7−2t, y = −2−7t, z = 1+5t**

**and Q lying on the line**

**x = −60−9t, y = −428+3t, z = −526−2t**

So I was a little confused on how to draw the lines in terms of t. I was also not sure how exactly we could use these equations to find specific coordinates, especially when the equations are already written in terms of x, y and z.

Any help?

Comment: the both lines should have not the same parameters

Comment: Are you allowed to use calculus to solve the problem?

Comment: This a simple variation of [one of your fairly recent previous questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2505164/265466). The answer to that question proceeds by finding the points on the lines that are nearest each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the two lines are given by
$$x=7-2t,y=-2-7t,z=1+5t$$
and 
$$x=-60-7s,y=-428+3s,z=-526-2s$$
so we have the distance by
$$d=\sqrt{(x_P-x_Q)^2+(y_p-y_Q)^2+(z_P-z_q)^2}$$
plugging the equations above in this formula we get
$$d=\sqrt{(7-2t+60+9s)^2+(-2-7t+428-3s)^2+(1+5t+526+2s)^2}$$
this is a function in $s,t$ and you can optimize this.
The result is $s=-5,t=7$